# how to calculate entropy from np histogram

Tags: python, numpy, histogram, entropy

I have an example of a histogram with:

```
mu1 = 10, sigma1 = 10
s1 = np.random.normal(mu1, sigma1, 100000)
```

and calculated

```
hist1 = np.histogram(s1, bins=50, range=(-10,10), density=True)
for i in hist1[0]:
    ent = -sum(i * log(abs(i)))
print (ent)
```

Now I want to find the entropy from the given histogram array, but since np.histogram returns two arrays, I'm having trouble calculating the entropy. How can I just call on first array of np.histogram and calculate entropy? I would also get math domain error for the entropy even if my code above is correct. :(

**Edit:
How do I find entropy when Mu = 0? and log(0) yields math domain error?

---

So the actual code I'm trying to write is:

```
mu1, sigma1 = 0, 1
mu2, sigma2 = 10, 1
s1 = np.random.normal(mu1, sigma1, 100000)
s2 = np.random.normal(mu2, sigma2, 100000)

hist1 = np.histogram(s1, bins=100, range=(-20,20), density=True)
data1 = hist1[0]
ent1 = -(data1*np.log(np.abs(data1))).sum() 

hist2 = np.histogram(s2, bins=100, range=(-20,20), density=True)
data2 = hist2[0]
ent2 = -(data2*np.log(np.abs(data2))).sum()
```

So far, the first example ent1 would yield nan, and the second, ent2, yields math domain error :(

Comment: Obviously, the problem is `log(0)` in undefined. But why do you use `range=(-20,20)`? I don't think `np.random.normal(mu2, sigma2, 100000)` produces any negative number! Anyway, as long as there are no points in some of the bins, you'll get this error!

Comment: Hey! Thanks! I got it sorted out. I used to trim out all the 0 data!

Comment: You're welcome! That's a good solution! If you think my answer helped, please accept the answer so the question will be marked!

Comment: Why do you use `abs`? The result of histogram should always be positive

Comment: "How do I find entropy when Mu = 0? and log(0) yields math domain error?" ... by **knowing** that the result should be 0, i.e. the mathematical limit as `i` goes to 0 of `i * abs(log(i))`, and special-casing it. This is effectively a math problem, not a programming problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can calculate the entropy using vectorized code:

```
import numpy as np

mu1 = 10
sigma1 = 10

s1 = np.random.normal(mu1, sigma1, 100000)
hist1 = np.histogram(s1, bins=50, range=(-10,10), density=True)
data = hist1[0]
ent = -(data*np.log(np.abs(data))).sum()
# output: 7.1802159512213191
```

But if you like to use a for loop, you may write:

```
import numpy as np
import math

mu1 = 10
sigma1 = 10

s1 = np.random.normal(mu1, sigma1, 100000)
hist1 = np.histogram(s1, bins=50, range=(-10,10), density=True)
ent = 0
for i in hist1[0]:
    ent -= i * math.log(abs(i))
print (ent)
# output: 7.1802159512213191
```

Comment: Thank you Mahdi for the answer! However, for me it is returning             RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  ent = -(i*np.log(abs(i))).sum()
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  ent = -(i*np.log(abs(i))).sum()
nan

Comment: and for the for loop, I get math domain error? What would be the problem?

Comment: @JinJeon: Could you produce a new set of `s1` values and repeat the above code? It seems some numbers are too close to zero.

Comment: hmm I'm still trying, and tried your version but still returns the same nan problem and math domain error.

Comment: Oh hmm weird. So if I try it on terminal and write it all manually again, it works. but whenever I import my .py file it shows the same error hmm :S

Comment: Maybe showing the whole code would help. Could you please update your question!?

Comment: Hey yep. I just attached my actual code. Didn't try to post the actual one, but I kept having issues so. Would really appreciate if you could help me out!

Comment: Isn't this solution only correct when the bin width is exactly 1? The histogram returns densities (not probabilities), while the entropy formular for densities requires multiplication of dx. Hence I would argue the formular in the for-loop should be multiplied with the bin width.

Answer (score 2):

Use `np.ma.log` to avoid inf and nan errors. `np.ma` is a masked numpy array.

Answer (score 2):

So for the ultimate copypaste experience, I just merged both existing answers (thank you all) into a more comprehensive numpy-native approach. Hope it helps!

```
def entropy(hist, bit_instead_of_nat=False):
    """
    given a list of positive values as a histogram drawn from any information source,
    returns the entropy of its probability mass function. Usage example:
      hist = [513, 487] # we tossed a coin 1000 times and this is our histogram
      print entropy(hist, True)  # The result is approximately 1 bit
      hist = [-1, 10, 10]; hist = [0] # this kind of things will trigger the warning
    """
    h = np.asarray(hist, dtype=np.float64)
    if h.sum()<=0 or (h<0).any():
        print "[entropy] WARNING, malformed/empty input %s. Returning None."%str(hist)
        return None
    h = h/h.sum()
    log_fn = np.ma.log2 if bit_instead_of_nat else np.ma.log
    return -(h*log_fn(h)).sum()
```

**Note:** Probability density function and probability mass function behave differently on discrete histograms, depending on the size of the bins. See the [np.histogram](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) docstring:

> density : bool, optional
>
> If False, the result will contain the number of samples in each bin.
> If True, the result is the value of the probability density function
> at the bin, normalized such that the integral over the range is 1.
> Note that the sum of the histogram values will not be equal to 1
> unless bins of unity width are chosen; it is not a probability mass
> function.
>
> Overrides the normed keyword if given.